# Is there a way to pass parameters to a job dynamically in Azure Databricks?

Tags: python, scheduler, jobs, azure-databricks

I'm looking for a solution to trigger an azure databricks job, keep the job running all the time and then passing parameters to functions dynamically.Is there a way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 2):

I tried this in Notebook activity:

1. pass the parameters to notebook activity under "Base Parameter" section
2. collect the parameter using the following statement

```
dbutils.widgets.text("parameter1", "","")
```

3. Assign it to a variable for the use in your notebook activity

```
var1 = dbutils.widgets.get("parameter1")
```

Hope it helps